# Observable - Multiple Subscibers

Tags: angularjs, typescript, publish-subscribe, rxjs, observable

I am very new on RxJS and Observables. I followed this tutorial ->

https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services

My question is,

There is:

> **OnePage**: manipulates and shows the answers
>
> **Service**: keeps the same answers
>
> **SecondPage**: manipulates and shows the answers

In that link, he subscribe the data to component data as follows

> ngOnInit() {
>       todosService.todos$.subscribe(updatedTodos => this.componentTodos = updatedTodos);
>       todosService.loadTodos(); }

which is in mine it is

> ```
> onPageWillEnter(){
>     this.service.answers$.subscribe(updatedAnswers => {
>         this.answers = updatedAnswers;
>         console.log("we subscribed from questions");
>     });
>     this.service.load().then((rootobject:RootObject) =>{
>         this.rootobject = rootobject;
>         this.questions = rootobject.Item.questions;
>         this.current_question = this.service.current_question;
>         this.pushNextImage(0);
>         console.log(this.answers, " Questions page loaded => then");
>     });
>     console.log(this.answers, " Questions page loaded");
> }
> ```

Everything is cool. I can update both Global "answers" and my local "answers" as follows.

> ```
> markQuestion(event){
>    this.current_question = this.questions[event.q_number];
>    this.current_question_number = event.q_number;
>    //Mark the answer in answers
>    this.answers[event.q_number-1] = event.val;
>    this.service._answersObserver.next(this.answers);
> }
> ```

After this when I console.log the "service.answers" it is updated aswell BUT.

At the SECOND PAGE:

```
onPageWillEnter(){
      this.service.answers$.subscribe(updatedAnswers => {
          this.answers = updatedAnswers;
          console.log("we subscribed from questions");
      });
      //this.service._answersObserver.next(this.service.answers);
      console.log(this.service.answers$);
      console.log(this.service.answers," Page loaded AnswerSheet" , this.answers ," => answer_list");
  }
```

IT DOESNT EVEN GO INTO SUBSCRIBE EVENT. NOTHING IS IN THE CONSOLE..UNLESS I do this:

this.service._answersObserver.next(this.service.answers);

Why is that ?

here is plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/c3fu5hsPZXslLegdeD0p?p=info

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you add the `this.service.answers$.subscribe` in the constructor of the `AnswerSheetPage` class and not in the `onPageWillEnter` method ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesnt work. Weird thing is I can see the global answers is setted correctly. It's like, Somehow I have to "wake up" the Observer by passing "its own goddamn value" to start broadcasting..